# Why std::setprecision shows not existed bits of precision and how to see real floating point

Tags: c++, precision

I would like to see float and double content, but i get a lot of additional unexpected precision digits.

```
printf("%.55f\n", 1.123456789012345);
cout << setprecision(100) << 1.123456789012345 << endl;
```

> 1.1234567890123450251138592648203484714031219482421875000
>   1.1234567890123450251138592648203484714031219482421875

while i was expecting something like this:

> 1.12345678901234500...
>   1.123456789012345

In Octave i also get unexpected output:

```
>> format long
>> single(1.123456789012345)
ans =  1.12345683574677
```

Comment: While not a straight duplicate, [this old question and its answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) might help you understand.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i thought before being stored in memory number got truncated to available precision bits and only saved bits considered afterwards.

Comment: The `std::setprecision` stream manipulator does not in any way enhance the underlying type precision. What you are seeing is just some random noise. The maximum precision you can set for `double` representation is: `std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10 + 1)`.

Comment: @Yola it does but each bit represent a binary fraction: try and extend this sequence to the 24 bit: 1st bit 1/2 (0.5); 2nd bit 1/4 (0.25) 3rd bit 1/8 (0.125); 4th bit 1/16 (0.0625) etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to see float and double content

You are actually observing the decimal number closest to `1.123456789012345` that can be **exactly** represented by the floating-point representation.
Note that some other decimal numbers like `1` can be represented exactly by the floating-point representation.

Thus, running:

```
std::cout << std::setprecision(100) << 1.123456789012345 << std::endl;
std::cout << std::setprecision(100) << 1.0 << std::endl;
std::cout << std::setprecision(100) << 1.1 << std::endl;
std::cout << std::setprecision(100) << 1.5 << std::endl;
```

will print:

```
1.1234567890123450251138592648203484714031219482421875
1
1.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625
1.5
```

I higly recommend reading excellent [*What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic*](http://www.itu.dk/~sestoft/bachelor/IEEE754_article.pdf) by David Goldberg.

Comment: The article by David Goldberg you propose to read is very complicated and has nothing to do with this simple issue. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Yota, While the article might seem subjectively hard to comprehend it describes the basic knowledge everyone working with floating-point numbers should have.

Comment: @AMA • Good call on Goldberg's article.  Hits the nail on the head for this kind of issue.